# Can not access prestashop admin menu except dashboard

Tags: nginx, prestashop-1.7

I installed prestashop in my localhost. I can login to admin and saw the dashboard. But when I went to other menu, it said 404 not found. The problem was in dashboard, it is using url like index.php?controller , but in other menu it is using admin/index.php. I installed the software under ps directory.

OK - http://localhost/ps/admin/index.php?controller=AdminDashboard&token=3fca2bcd5f31ce3c1cdf951bf5620720#/preview
FAIL - http://localhost/ps/admin/index.php/sell/catalog/products?_token=IIPIHFzRMTdRMvjXGeCiFocCWVXBiwUhWgJIAhgzvtA

Here is my nginx default site configuration inside server {}

```
location /ps {
        root /var/www/;
        index index.php;
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
location ~ /ps/(.+\.php)$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        }
}
```

I am using nginx version 1.18.0 and prestashop version 1.7.8.3 on ubuntu 20.04.4.

My question is, how to fix the nginx setting especially the try_files part so that I can access prestashop's other menu? If that is not possible, how to disable pretty url in prestashop?

Answer (score 0):

Prestashop comes with built-in Apache rewriting rules,
so using a NGINX only enviroment could be troublesome.

You preferably have to switch to Apache as-persystem requirements :
https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/basics/installation/system-requirements/
or consider using Nginx as a reverse proxy for static resources and Apache to serve PHP requests, so native htaccess will work out of the box.

Anyway , have a look at Nginx-specific Prestashop rules:

https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/basics/installation/nginx/

to be integrated in your conf file.

While, in order to completely disable URL rewriting,
you can act on a backoffice setting **"URL rewriting"** in **SEO&URL** part, if you are not able to reach that page, you can just adjust "**PS_REWRITING_SETTINGS**" to **0** in ps_configuration table in your database.

I'm not sure if this will work with the backoffice routes that are now based on Symfony framework, though.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using Apache and it worked.